# Dialog in AsyncTask onPreExecute()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my app I am using an calling `AsyncTask-A` to check if the user is new and call `AsyncTask-B` to prompt user for a new password and reset it. I came to know that displaying the Dialog should be done on `onPreExecute()` and then change the password (using `KSOAP`) on `doInBackground()`. However, the problem is that `alert.show();` does not wait and *doInBackground()* gets called immediately breaking the logic. Here is the relevant part of code:

```
private class AsyncTaskPasswordResetter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(login.this);
        builder.setMessage("Please enter new password");
        final EditText input = new EditText(login.this);
        input.setText("");
        builder.setView(input);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org/", "ChangeParentPassword");
                        request.addProperty(MyUtils.CreateProp("Username", userName, String.class));
                        request.addProperty(MyUtils.CreateProp("Password", password, String.class));
                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11) {{dotNet = true;}};
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("http://hannuveda.online/default.asmx");

                        try {
                            androidHttpTransport.call("http://tempuri.org/ChangeParentPassword", envelope);
                            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

                            if (response.toString().equals("OK")) {
                                setTextViewstatus("passed\n");
                            } else {
                                setTextViewstatus("failed\n");
                                isError = true;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            setTextViewstatus("error\n");
                            isError = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        input.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if(isError)
            SetLoginButtonEnability(true);
        setTextViewstatus("wait...");
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(login.this, trackbus.class);
                    intent.putExtra("UserID", userID);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have UI logic inside your AsyncTask? How about you do the UI logic outside and use callbacks.

Comment: I invoke AsyncTaskA to check is the user is new, if user is new I call AsyncTaskB from it's onPostExecute(). In AsyncTaskB I need to prompt the user (using Dialog) for a new password. Any tip on how to implement this using the logic you said ?

Answer (score 0):

To have a better control over sequential `AsyncTask`'s it is a good idea to use callbacks.

e.g.

```
public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask < String, Void, HttpResponse > {

private final LoginTaskCallback callback;

public LoginTask(LoginTaskCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}


@Override
protected HttpResponse doInBackground(String...params) {
    // do network stuff
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse response) {
    // just and example
    if (response.getStatus() == 200)
        callback.success();
    else
        callback.failure();
}

public interface LoginTaskCallback {
    void failure();
    void success();
}
}
```

Then you can `execute` the task and receive the callback an do whatever next in this case start `AsyncTaskB`.

```
 new LoginTask(new LoginTask.LoginTaskCallback() {
            @Override
            public void failure() {
               // stop here smth went wrong 
            }

            @Override
            public void success() {
               // start next task
            }
        }).execute();
```

Comment: Where to display the dialog box ?

Comment: @AkshayJ In your `Activity` or somewhere where you can call the AsyncTask. You only want to pass the `username` and `password` to the Task and execute it.

Comment: The problem is that I need to prompt the user for new password and  change the password after OK is clicked. But Show() is not blocking. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: @AkshayJ Did you even read my answer at all? I told you not to put your `Dialog` logic into the Asynctask. You have two callbacks where you can show it in case of success or failure. Even before that you can show the `Dialog` before you start the task, because you need to pass the `username` and `password` either way.

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove UI code from `AsyncTask`. Keep those in `Activity`/`Fragments`
2) On click of button, invoke `AsyncTask` which will take care of Network Operation and get back response to the caller

Below code should be not be in AsyncTask

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(login.this);
        builder.setMessage("Please enter new password");
        final EditText input = new EditText(login.this);
        input.setText("");
        builder.setView(input);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        //This invocation is explained in details given below
                        new NetworkAsyncTask(ActivityClass.this).execute();
                    }
                }
        );
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        input.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Create either Separate AsyncTask which will take parameters , so that the same can be used to process other requests

Its advisable to create interface with methods, which will get back the processed data to the callers

```
public interface OnAsyncTaskComplition {
    public void networkResponse(Object responseObject);

}
```

Implement this interface in UI class from where network requests are sent

```
class DemoActivity extends Activity implements OnAsyncTaskComplition{

    @Override
    public void networkResponse(Object responseObject) {
     // call back will come here for failure or success

    }

}
```

Following will the the AsyncTask for this purpose

```
class NetworkAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Boolean,Boolean>{
      Activity activity;
      Object responce;
      ProgressDialog dialog;
      public NetworkAsyncTask (Activity activity) {
         super();
         this.activity = activity;
      }
      @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //Show a waiting screen
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Please wait", "Processing.........");

        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
         // Do all your processing here
         //assign the response to OBJECT responce
         this.responce = processedResult;
         //return true of false based on the success
         return true;//or false based on the success
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
            //dismiss the dialog shown for processing
            if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())
              {dialog.dismiss();}
            activity.networkResponse(responce );
        }

}
```

Comment: @MuratK.  Nobody was born as coders! Everybody learned from mistakes and trials. Akshay J is not at all from Android background. Which is explicit from his question. We as SO , should help if the question is relevant / with enough code , than just ideas and links. So I guess the help was relevant. I did not interfere in your answer . I expect the same from you.

Answer (score 0):

In AsyncTaskA check if the user is new, if it is,  then instead of running a new AsyncTask just run an AlertDialog, through which you get data from user. 

onClickListener pass the user data as a parameter list to AsycnTaskB